# Render template file and get the content without applying the state

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I know that [`state.show_sls`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.show_sls) renders and display a state.

I would like to know how to render a template file that is used inside a state and display its content without needing to apply the state.

Is there a way to use the  [salt's jinja renderer](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html) from the command line to do that?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way, but I work with [masterless vagrant boxes](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/salt.html) in this case. Inside I do apply the states and check on the box, how it looks like.

Comment: You can see the differences between salt version and the installed one, without applying the state, using `test=True` parameter on `state.sls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I have come to the command [salt.module.cp](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.get_template) and it goes like this:

`salt-call cp.get_template salt://file.jinja /dev/stdout`

It renders a file as a template and prints it on the terminal.

I use it a lot while developing formulas to check my templates.

Comment: if you get the lovely cryptic error `Passed invalid arguments: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found.` as an error, that means either your saltenv or the file path is incorrect. Also, note that `salt://file.jinja` in the example really probably is `salt://file.sls` containing jinja templating.